# Why is dataObjectDeserializer.getObject() not present?

Tags: spring, stripe-payments

I have created a spring-boot server for handling stripe webhooks.
However, webhooks are working -  I am getting an event, but when i try to get the value of dataObjectDeserializer.getObject() its null. Any ideas why that might be and how to fix it.

Here is the code:

```
    Event event = null;

    try {
        event = Webhook.constructEvent(
                payload, sigHeader, endpointSecret
        );
    } catch (SignatureVerificationException e) {
        // Invalid signature
        logger.info("Webhook error while validating signature.");
        return "";
    }

    EventDataObjectDeserializer dataObjectDeserializer = event.getDataObjectDeserializer();
    StripeObject stripeObject = null;
    if (dataObjectDeserializer.getObject().isPresent()) {
        stripeObject = dataObjectDeserializer.getObject().get();
    } else {
        // Deserialization failed, probably due to an API version mismatch.
        // Refer to the Javadoc documentation on `EventDataObjectDeserializer` for
        // instructions on how to handle this case, or return an error here.
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran into the same issue recently.

In my case (Which I believe might be yours as well). Is that the Event is not being properly deserialized because a version mismatch between the API you are using in your account and the models of the Stripe SDK in your project. You can check this by looking into: Event.getApiVersion() and Stripe.API_VERSION.
If they differ then you will need to properly upgrade them and take in consideration migration guidelines if they apply to your scenario.

On my case since it was a first time I didn't need to go through any migration and I just simply when to my dash board and upgrade the sdk:

[Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCiPR.png) Note: It displays rollback because I did upgrade it. If you haven't you will have a "Upgrade" option available.

You can find more info on their documentation page:

[Upgrade Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#how-can-i-upgrade-my-api)
[Versioning](https://stripe.com/docs/api/versioning)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had the same issue. I managed to resolve it by pulling the latest version of `"com.stripe" % "stripe-java"` which is `24.13.0` as of today

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for this.

Upgrade your sprive-java library as well. I was in 20.68 and as soon as I upgraded to 24.0 the problem was solved!